# Keras validation loss is calculating incorrectly

Tags: python, keras, gpu

My model trains fine on a CPU machine but I am running into an issue when trying to rerun it on our cluster (using a single GPU and the same dataset). When training on a GPU machine validation loss and accuracy are not improving from epoch to epoch (see below).This was not the case on a CPU machine (I was able to achieve validation accuracy ~0.8 after 20 epochs)

**Details:**

Keras 2.1.3

TensforFlow backend

70/20/10 train/dev/test

~ 7000 images

model is based on ResNet50

**Code**

```
    import sys
    import math
    import os
    import glob

    from keras import applications
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.models import Sequential, Model 
    from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
    from keras import backend as k 
    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, EarlyStopping

    ############ Training parameters ##################
    img_width, img_height = 224, 224
    batch_size = 32
    epochs = 100


    ############ Define the data ##################
    train_data_dir = '/mnt/data/train'
    validation_data_dir = '/mnt/data/validate'

    train_data_dir_class1 = os.path.join(train_data_dir,'class1', '*.jpg')
    train_data_dir_class2 = os.path.join(train_data_dir, 'class2', '*.jpg')

    validation_data_dir_class1 = os.path.join(validation_data_dir, 'class1', '*.jpg')
    validation_data_dir_class2 = os.path.join(validation_data_dir, 'class2', '*.jpg')

    # number of training and validation samples
    nb_train_samples = len(glob.glob(train_data_dir_class1)) + len(glob.glob(train_data_dir_class2))
    nb_validation_samples = len(glob.glob(validation_data_dir_class1)) + len(glob.glob(validation_data_dir_class2))


    ############ Define the model ##################
    model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights = "imagenet",
                                           include_top = False,
                                           input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))

    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Adding a FC layer
    x = model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    predictions = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")(x)

    # creating the final model 
    model_final = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)

    # compile the model 
    model_final.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                        optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001,
                                                    beta_1 = 0.9,
                                                    beta_2 = 0.999,
                                                    epsilon = 1e-10),
                        metrics = ["accuracy"])

    # train and test generators 
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                       horizontal_flip = True,
                                       fill_mode = "nearest",
                                       zoom_range = 0.3,
                                       width_shift_range = 0.3,
                                       height_shift_range = 0.3,
                                       rotation_range = 30)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                        target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                                        class_mode = "binary",
                                                        seed = 2018)

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                            target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                                            class_mode = "binary",
                                                            seed = 2018)

    early = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', min_delta = 10e-5, patience = 10, verbose = 1, mode = 'auto')
    performance_log = CSVLogger('/mnt/results/vanilla_model_log.csv', separator = ',', append = False)

    # Train the model
    model_final.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(train_generator.samples / batch_size),
                              epochs = epochs,
                              validation_data = validation_generator,
                              validation_steps = math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                              callbacks = [early, performance_log])

    # Save the model
    model_final.save('/mnt/results/vanilla_model.h5')
```

**Training Log**

```
Epoch 1/100
151/151 [==============================] - 237s 2s/step - loss: 0.7234 - acc: 0.5240 - val_loss: 0.9899 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 2/100
151/151 [==============================] - 65s 428ms/step - loss: 0.6491 - acc: 0.6228 - val_loss: 1.0248 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 3/100
151/151 [==============================] - 65s 429ms/step - loss: 0.6091 - acc: 0.6648 - val_loss: 1.0377 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 4/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 426ms/step - loss: 0.5829 - acc: 0.6968 - val_loss: 1.0459 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 5/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 427ms/step - loss: 0.5722 - acc: 0.7070 - val_loss: 1.0472 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 6/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 427ms/step - loss: 0.5582 - acc: 0.7166 - val_loss: 1.0501 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 7/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 424ms/step - loss: 0.5535 - acc: 0.7188 - val_loss: 1.0492 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 8/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 426ms/step - loss: 0.5377 - acc: 0.7287 - val_loss: 1.0209 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 9/100
151/151 [==============================] - 64s 425ms/step - loss: 0.5328 - acc: 0.7368 - val_loss: 1.0062 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 10/100
151/151 [==============================] - 65s 432ms/step - loss: 0.5296 - acc: 0.7381 - val_loss: 1.0016 - val_acc: 0.5425
Epoch 11/100
151/151 [==============================] - 65s 430ms/step - loss: 0.5231 - acc: 0.7419 - val_loss: 1.0021 - val_acc: 0.5425
```

Since I was able to get good results on a CPU machine, I hypothesized that validation loss/accuracy must be calculated incorrectly at the end of each epoch. To test this theory I used train set as validation set: if validation loss/accuracy is calculated correctly we should see roughly the same values for train and validation loss and accuracy. As you may see below, validation loss values are not the same as training loss values, which makes me believe validation loss is calculated incorrectly at the end of each epoch. **Why does it happen? What are the possible solutions?**

**Modified Code**

```
    import sys
    import math
    import os
    import glob

    from keras import applications
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.models import Sequential, Model 
    from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
    from keras import backend as k 
    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, EarlyStopping

    ############ Training parameters ##################
    img_width, img_height = 224, 224
    batch_size = 32
    epochs = 100


    ############ Define the data ##################
    train_data_dir = '/mnt/data/train'
    validation_data_dir = '/mnt/data/train' # redefined validation set to test accuracy of validation loss/accuracy calculations

    train_data_dir_class1 = os.path.join(train_data_dir,'class1', '*.jpg')
    train_data_dir_class2 = os.path.join(train_data_dir, 'class2', '*.jpg')

    validation_data_dir_class1 = os.path.join(validation_data_dir, 'class1', '*.jpg')
    validation_data_dir_class2 = os.path.join(validation_data_dir, 'class2', '*.jpg')

    # number of training and validation samples
    nb_train_samples = len(glob.glob(train_data_dir_class1)) + len(glob.glob(train_data_dir_class2))
    nb_validation_samples = len(glob.glob(validation_data_dir_class1)) + len(glob.glob(validation_data_dir_class2))


    ############ Define the model ##################
    model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights = "imagenet",
                                           include_top = False,
                                           input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))

    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Adding a FC layer
    x = model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    predictions = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")(x)

    # creating the final model 
    model_final = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)

    # compile the model 
    model_final.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                        optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001,
                                                    beta_1 = 0.9,
                                                    beta_2 = 0.999,
                                                    epsilon = 1e-10),
                        metrics = ["accuracy"])

    # train and test generators 
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                       horizontal_flip = True,
                                       fill_mode = "nearest",
                                       zoom_range = 0.3,
                                       width_shift_range = 0.3,
                                       height_shift_range = 0.3,
                                       rotation_range = 30)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                        target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                                        class_mode = "binary",
                                                        seed = 2018)

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                            target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                                            class_mode = "binary",
                                                            seed = 2018)

    early = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', min_delta = 10e-5, patience = 10, verbose = 1, mode = 'auto')
    performance_log = CSVLogger('/mnt/results/vanilla_model_log.csv', separator = ',', append = False)

    # Train the model
    model_final.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(train_generator.samples / batch_size),
                              epochs = epochs,
                              validation_data = validation_generator,
                              validation_steps = math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                              callbacks = [early, performance_log])

    # Save the model
    model_final.save('/mnt/results/vanilla_model.h5')
```

**Training log for the modified code:**

```
Epoch 1/100
151/151 [==============================] - 251s 2s/step - loss: 0.6804 - acc: 0.5910 - val_loss: 0.6923 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 2/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.6258 - acc: 0.6523 - val_loss: 0.6938 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 3/100
151/151 [==============================] - 88s 580ms/step - loss: 0.5946 - acc: 0.6874 - val_loss: 0.7001 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 4/100
151/151 [==============================] - 88s 580ms/step - loss: 0.5718 - acc: 0.7086 - val_loss: 0.7036 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 5/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.5634 - acc: 0.7157 - val_loss: 0.7067 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 6/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.5467 - acc: 0.7243 - val_loss: 0.7099 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 7/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.5392 - acc: 0.7317 - val_loss: 0.7096 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 8/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.5287 - acc: 0.7387 - val_loss: 0.7083 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 9/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 575ms/step - loss: 0.5306 - acc: 0.7385 - val_loss: 0.7088 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 10/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 577ms/step - loss: 0.5303 - acc: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.7111 - val_acc: 0.5469
Epoch 11/100
151/151 [==============================] - 87s 578ms/step - loss: 0.5157 - acc: 0.7474 - val_loss: 0.7143 - val_acc: 0.5469
```

Comment: Could you point to the fragment of code where you made your training and validation data the same?

Comment: In the second block of code you can find: 
validation_data_dir = '/mnt/data/train' # redefined validation set to test accuracy of validation loss/accuracy calculations

Comment: @AnnaV Have you found the answer to this? I'm experiencing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick idea that might help.

I think **image labels are randomly assigned by two image data generator** and trained.
And two image data generator gives different label distribution.
That's why training accuracy goes up while validation set remains around 50%.

I haven't entirely checked documentation of data image generator. Hope this might helps.

Argument **classes** for flow_from_directory() describes a way of setting up training labels.

> classes: optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs',
>   'cats']). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be
>   automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under
>   directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different
>   class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label
>   indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping
>   from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute
>   class_indices.